# Angular data sharing architecture

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services, angular-observable, angular-state-managmement

I feel like I fundamentally misunderstand one part of Angular, imagine the following:

You have a navbar component which shows the logged in user, something like:

```html
<nav *ngIf="user$ | async as user">user.name</nav>
```

then you have a user-edit component, something like:

```html
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user" class="form">
  <input [(ngModel)]="user.name">
</div>
```

###### where `user$` is an `Observable` that one gets from a service.

Now in the app you naturally show a navbar and the other components, this means both components need the same data. To prevent multiple api calls you can use an `cachedResponse` or use `shareReplay()` within a `user.service.ts`. Great!

Here's my question, making the service this way requires a lot more code than, for instance, sharing a `user` object directly from a `service` like so:

```js
export class UserService implements OnInit {
  public user: User = new User;
  
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<User>('api.com/user').subscribe((user: User) => this.user = user);
  }

  updateUser() {
    this.http.post('api.com/user', this.user).subscribe((user: User) => this.user = user);
  }

}
```

And in both components just add:
`constructor(public userService: UserService) {}`
and use it in the template like so:

```html
<nav>userService.user.name</nav>
```

and:

```html
<div class="form">
  <input [(ngModel)]="userService.user.name">
  <button (click)="userService.updateUser"></button>
</div>
```

Apart from not using the Angular Async Pipe what would be bad about a structure like this?
If you update the name all other components also get updated.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919028/angular-why-subscriptions-why-not-to-use-services-properties-in-components) question on here but the all the answers are non-issues (it seems to me). Just to answer them:

1. **Memory leak**, no because http services unsubscribe in Angular (I would only use this for http calls).
2. **Value update is not track**, this could be an issue if you want to mutate values from the same observable but if you would want that one would make a different observable.
3. **Separation of concerns**, what is bad about having one global user object? Only components which use the `UserService` have access.
4. Not really an issue with this type of architecture.

Why would this be bad?, or rather why don't I see any examples of people doing this.

Answer (score 0):

When you stream data via Observables, api has to be called only once.

Here, in the nav component, you call the api and share the data using a common observable.

But if you prefer the second method, each and every component that make use of the service has to call that api. Number of calls to the server will increase. Not much of that issue, still, the first one makes your code look clean.

Comment: "Every component that make use of the service has to call that api". No the `UserService` would be the only file that calls the api (once when ngOnInit runs) and shares the result using the `public user`. That's what makes it so clean

Comment: Yes, if you are using public. But I would go private for being more secure. Thanks.